# How to convert a string in PHP using different formats ( xliff segments )

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I wish to convert the following strings, from source to target and back again from target to source.

```
$strSource = '<g id="5">fist test string</g> <d id="20">some random string</d>';
$strTarget = '{1}fist test string{2}some random string{3}';
```

The solution I found is using arrays and preg_replace.

I'm just wondering if there is an efficient solution to make this conversions using xslt. Using additional data is allowed. The data can contain any helping information.

Updated:

This is my solution for target->source using preg_match_all, just to be understood better:

```
preg_match_all('/(<.*>)(?!\s*<)/U', $strSource, $arrResult);
echo preg_replace('/{(\d+)}/e', 'arrResult[1]["$1" - 1]', $strTarget);
```

Comment: `preg_replace` is the fastest way i know ... `$strSource` is not a valid `XML` or `HTML` `XSLT` would not work ....

Comment: You cannot have a solution for target to source -- no way to know what values to use for the `id` attribute. Therefore your statement that you have a solution isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 2.0 supports regular expressions, on the other side here is an XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSuffix" select="'FR'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat('{',g[last()]/@id +1, '}')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="g">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat('{',@id, '}',
            substring-before(., '_'), '_', $pSuffix
           )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (your "string", wrapped into a single top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
  <g id="1">TEST_EN</g> <g id="2">TEST_EN</g>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
{1}TEST_FR{2}TEST_FR{3}
```

**The reverse transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSuffix" select="'EN'"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="makeXml">
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
   <xsl:param name="pId" select="1"/>

     <xsl:if test=
       "contains($pText, '{') and contains($pText, '}')">
      <xsl:variable name="vPiece" select=
        "substring-before(substring-after($pText, '}'), '{')"/>
      <g id="{$pId}"><xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(substring-before($vPiece, '_'), '_', $pSuffix)"/></g>
      <xsl:call-template name="makeXml">
       <xsl:with-param name="pId" select="$pId +1"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
          "substring-after(substring-after($pText, '}'), '{')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the result of the first transformation** (again wrapped in a single top element to make it well-formed XML document):

```
<t>{1}TEST_FR{2}TEST_FR{3}</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<g id="1">TEST_EN</g><g id="2">TEST_EN</g>
```

Comment: The example I gave it's really basic. Your solution is great but I was wondering if there is a way to rebuild the source without using "known" xml structure. I update the question example.

Comment: @danip: Good, but for your latest example it isn't possible (with any method -- including regex) to do the reverse transformation -- the values of the `id` attributes aren't known. The first transformation is as easy as in my answer.

Comment: Well It is possible by using the source as a base. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @danip: Using the source as a base??? Then just produce the source directly! Please, correct this inconsistency in the question and then the solution is, again, straight-forward.

Comment: @danip: Still, how would the values 5 and 20 for the `id` attributes magically be generated from target??? If you are using an additional array, please, explain that using additional data (the array in your case) is allowed and what this data may contain. As of now, this question is ambiguous and contradictory.